# Отображение тега <summary> как region

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы описание метода/свойства/поля при свернутом теге , выглядело не как обычно:

```
+ [/// <summary> ...]
```

А выводило содержимое(описание) метода (так работает #region).

```
+ [Описание метода ололо ...]
```

Было бы очень удобно, если весь класс свернуть (Ctrl+M+M)
И потом не приходилось разворачивать теги , чтобы увидеть описание метода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставьте новую студию. В новой Visual Studio 2015 RC свернутое описание выглядит как

```
[+]    /// <summary> some summary
```

Comment: Да, недавно поставил студию, действительно внедрили эту фичу, но пока не готов переходить на новую, спасибо за ответ.